# Mysql UPDATE w/ JOIN after ALTER TABLE not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large SQL file which is used to migrate an old legacy DB. Dozens of tables are created, many are ALTER'ed and many still UPDATE'ed - this is one such snippet:

...

```
ALTER TABLE `db1`.`rpi_consumables`
    ADD COLUMN `id_inventory` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `cname`;

UPDATE `db1`.`rpi_consumables` AS t1 JOIN db2.erp_inventory AS t2 ON t1.cnumber = t2.part_number SET t1.id_inventory = t2.id_primary;
```

...

If I run this code separate from the rest of the code it seems to work fine.

EDIT | The problem is the UPDATE - the ALTER works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem with `update`? do you get an error? if so, what is it?

Comment: please show your exact error message

Comment: That's the thing...no error. And it works when I run this after the other queries. I'm thinking the alter doesn't complete before the update somehow...I dunno so weird. Everything else seems to work

Comment: What do you *expect* the result of your update to be, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: If the table is not empty, you can't add a `NOT NULL` column without a default value.

Comment: Interesting...didn't catch that. Will try tomorrow at work. Thing is...the alter works fine...always. The update only works when I run it after other commands...

Comment: If the `ALTER` works - what is stored in that column?

Comment: However - If the UPDATE statement returns no error but noting is updated, that might mean, that the join returns 0 rows. Maybe `erp_inventory` is empty at that time.

Comment: Just an INT field its an id to another table - I am updating rpi_consumables with the ID to erp_inventory. When I run the UPDATE separately (even with the ALTER) before it works fine. :s

Comment: I don't know WTF is happening here - so frustrating. I set the default value to ZERO - still will not update the ID. I moved the column to the middle of the table - no dice. We are not using a proper migration library but instead RAW SQL queries and a couple stored procs...

Comment: I think I may have figured it out - @PaulSpiegel had the answer :) so easily overlooked but s obvious in retrospect.